# postgresql and docker: which directory is needed to persist data

Tags: postgresql, docker

In `postgresql` which are the directories we need to persist in general so that i can use the same data again even i rebuild

Like:

I know the main directory:

```
/var/lib/postgres or  /var/lib/postgres/data (small confusion, which one)
```

and any other like the logs etc

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `PGDATA` environment variable in your docker container to specify where postgres will save its database files.

From the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) of the official postgres Docker image:

> - **PGDATA:**
>
>   This optional variable can be used to define another location - like a
>     subdirectory - for the database files. The default is
>     /var/lib/postgresql/data, but if the data volume you're using is a
>     filesystem mountpoint (like with GCE persistent disks), Postgres
>     initdb recommends a subdirectory (for example
>     /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ) be created to contain the data.

Additionally from the `postgres` documentation transaction log files are also written to `PGDATA`:

> By default the transaction log is stored in a subdirectory of the
>   main Postgres data folder (PGDATA).

So by default the `postgres` image will write database files to `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

To answer your question it should be sufficient to bind mount a directory to `/var/lib/postgresql/data` inside of your `postgres` container.

Comment: so what about `/var/lib/postgresql/`